# Low quality flag does not display on old answers

Tags: bug, flagging

This has now happened a couple of times where the low quality flagging option is missing on old answers. You only have the options to flag the answer as spam, rude, not an answer and then the custom moderator message option.

Because of this, I flag the answer for moderator attention, which in my honest opinion is incorrect as we can handle the flag as a community if we could flag it as low quality. I cannot flag the answer as spam or rude, because it clearly does not fit in that section, Also, these flags punishes the user who posted the answer, so simply flagging it as spam or rude might later get the user banned, and that for nothing.

I also cannot flag the answer as not being an answer, because although the quality is really poor of the answer itself, it does qualify as an answer.

How should we handle old answers which we cannot flag as correctly being low quality due to the absence of that flag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is not a bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635):

> the VLQ flag is no longer available on posts older than 7 days

The idea is that the posts that truly fit in the VLQ category are quite obvious, and so the fact that nobody recognized a post as VLQ for a week means it doesn't really fit the flag. The remaining options are:

1. Flag as not an answer, if it does not answer the question.
2. Downvote if it's a wrong answer.
3. Vote to delete (for 20K users) if it's not only wrong but also completely useless.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info and link.